# an empty bibliography page

Tags: bibliographies, header-footer, memoir, pagestyle, emptypage

please I want my two pages of bibliography not paginated

```
\input{adb}
\thispagestyle{empty}
```

but the result is that only the second page is unnumbered.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Have you tried placing `\thispagestyle{empty}` both before and after `\input adb`? Alternatively, have you considered running `\clearpage\pagestyle(empty}` before loading the contents of the external file?

Comment: yes i tried but same probleme ..

Comment: Please provide a full minimal example such that we know how this bibliography is made as that will affect any proposed solutions.

Comment: \pagenumbering{arabic}

\input{chap1} 
\input{chap2} 
\input{chap3}
\input{chap4}

\input{conc}
\

\pagestyle{empty}
\input{adb}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\includepdf[pages={1}]{abstrat.pdf}
\thispagestyle{empty}